# How to get last auto increment value in a table? VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

How would you get the last Primary Key/Auto Increment value in a table using OleDb?

I need to get this value so I can create a folder for a record before it is added so that files can be copied to the folder when it is added.

Any idea?
I have tried as following.

`@@Identity` 'Need to insert a record first and I can't do that without copying the files first
`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` 'Doesn't work with `OleDb`

This is the error message I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Tried it, still just returns the PK column name

Comment: Does it really return the Primary Key Column's name?  That is strange.   It should return a number.

Comment: Could you also post a few lines of the code where it is failing.  Might not be your SQL that is failing.

Comment: Just fixed it. Instead of calling the Item with Record.Item("UserID"), I called it using Record.Item(0)

Comment: Whilst this will work, you should be aware that in a multi-user scenario there is a potential for another user to add a new record at the wrong moment and thus bump the MAX(ID) again.  May or may not be a problem in your situation, but something you should bear in mind.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this because of The Jet 4.0 provider supports `@@Identity`,
[Reference](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record)

```
Dim query As String = "Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (?)"
Dim query2 As String = "Select @@Identity"
Dim ID As Integer
Dim connect As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connect)
  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Category.Text)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.CommandText = query2
    ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I'm not inserting like I stated above. I did try that before though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')
```

It Will retrun Last ID(If it's Auto increment) of your Table

Answer (score 0):

[reference](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-get-the-identity/autonumber-value-for-the-row-i-inserted.html)

```
**c#**
string query = "Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (?)";
string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
int ID;
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Category.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = query2;
    ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}

**VB**
Dim query As String = "Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (?)"
Dim query2 As String = "Select @@Identity"
Dim ID As Integer
Dim connect As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connect)
  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Category.Text)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.CommandText = query2
    ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
  End Using
End Using
```

[refer](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record)

Comment: Not inserting first though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Check if NULL first :

```
Select if(IsNull(Max(ColName)),1,Max(ColName) + 1 ) From YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this (vb.net)
'''
Dim lastrecord As Integer
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select IDENT_CURRENT('tbluom')+1", conn)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    lastrecord = command.ExecuteScalar()
    txt_uomid.Text = lastrecord
    MsgBox(lastrecord)
    Dim encode As String = txt_uomid.Text '"99999"
    Dim encint As Integer = Integer.Parse(encode) '+ 1
    encode = "00" & "-" & encint.ToString("00000").Substring(1, 4)
    MsgBox(encode)
    ''''
```

Comment: you can also try Max record
'''
select max(customer_id)+1 as xyz from tblcustomer
''''